# Referenced data is reset to its default values after being copied

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, data-sharing

I have an issue with data seemingly being reset to its default values.
The class is as follows (objectIDs is a simple enumeration):

```
public class Output_args: EventArgs {
    public objectIDs outputtype;
    public int internalID;
    public int verdict;
    public int outputID;
    public long entrytime;

    public Output_args Copy() {
        Output_args args = new Output_args();
        args.entrytime = this.entrytime;
        args.internalID = this.internalID;
        args.outputID = this.outputID;
        args.outputtype = this.outputtype;
        args.verdict = this.verdict;
        return args;
    }
}
```

The following code creates the object. It runs in a specific thread, let's say Thread1.

```
class Class1 {
EventWaitHandle ewh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
public event EventHandler<Output_args> newOutput;
public void readInput(){
    List<Output_args> newoutputlist = new List<Output_args>();
    /* 
    * code to determine the outputs
    */
    Output_args args = new Output_args();
    args.outputtype = objectIDs.stepID;
    args.internalID = step[s].ID;
    args.verdict = verdict;
    args.entrytime = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    newoutputlist.Add(args.Copy());
    if (newOutput != null && newoutputlist.Count > 0) {
    // several outputs are being sent sequentially but for simplicity i've removed the for-loop and decision tree
        try {
            newOutput(null, newoutputlist[0].Copy());
        } catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
}
```

1 of the subscribers to this event has the following code. The processor method runs on a thread of a camerafeed. The newOutput event handler is being run on Thread1.

```
class Class2: Form {
    private Output_args lastoutput = new Output_args();
    public void newOutput(object sender, Output_args args) {
        lock (lastoutput) {
            lastoutput = args.Copy();
        }
    }

    public void processor(){
        lock (lastoutput) {
            if (lastoutput.entrytime + 10000000 > System.DateTime.Now.Ticks) {
            // do something
             }
        }
    }
}
```

When the eventhandler 'newOutput' of Class2 is being called, the debugger shows that the copy works as expected and 'entrytime' is given the expected number of ticks.
However, when the processor method wants to read the 'entrytime', its value is 0. All other fields also have their default value assigned.
I've tried replacing the object 'lastoutput' with a simple field of the type long and removed the locks but the results are the same: it gets assigned properly in 'newOutput' but has its default value (0) in the processor method.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: A simplified working example code would be great.

Comment: And are you SURE it's the same instance of Class2 ?

Comment: I was running 2 instances and the eventhandler was added to only 1 which caused the confusion for me. It's fixed now so thnx!

Answer (score 0):

you should not lock on the object `lastoutput`, but on another object, because you reassign the field.

The processor start and lock on the default field instance `new Output_args()` initialized with default values

```
class Class2: Form {
    private object mylock = new object();
    private Output_args lastoutput;
    public void newOutput(object sender, Output_args args) {
        lock (mylock) {
            lastoutput = args.Copy();
        }
    }

    public void processor(){
        lock (mylock) {
            if (lastoutput == null) {
               //nothing to consume yet
            }
            else if (lastoutput.entrytime + 10000000 > System.DateTime.Now.Ticks) {
               // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this discard lastouput if consumer is slower than producer. You can use a queue ( or another collection ) as buffer if needed.

```
class Class2 {
    private Queue<Output_args> outputs = new Queue<Output_args>();

    public void newOutput(object sender, Output_args args) {
        lock (outputs) {
            outputs.Enqueue(args.Copy());
        }
    }

    public void processor(){
        lock (outputs) {
            if (outputs.Count > 0) {
                var lastoutput = outputs.Dequeue();

                if (lastoutput.entrytime + 10000000 > System.DateTime.Now.Ticks) {
                // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/daHVD1

Comment: These seems to only add an extra reference in the chain. Either way I've tried this solution and something interesting came up. The Queue list receives all the outputs but in the processor loop, the count remains 0. So it appears they're 2 differant objects but in visual studio, it highlights both variables when 1 of them is selected, showing they're the same. I'm going to check if somehow i have 2 instances running but i doubt it. Also i'm only interested in the latest output. The others can be ignored.